# PHPUnit symfony2 faking parameters.yml

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I need to test some functionality with PHPUnit. I got isolated database for running tests but still some functionality depends on the parameters.yml where I add user IDs or IP addresses. Is there any way of creating fake parameters.yml for tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a config file as config_test.yml, create parameters_test.yml and inside config_test, import parameters_test.yml.

When you run your test set the ENV variable to "test"

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to unit-test your bundle with parameters configured in several different combinations.